# Which variable keep/get rid in a time series model?

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics, time-series, forecasting, svar

Let s say I have a big VAR model with many variables. Then I run the model. How can I know which variables I should keep or get rid of if I want to ameliorate my model ?

What if my model has so many variables I can't remove it one variable after the other ? How to select the variables ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the purpose of your model? Why do you want to decrease the number of variables?

Comment: Here is a fairly modern approach to VAR estimation and model selection: Nicholson et al. ["High Dimensional Forecasting via Interpretable Vector
Autoregression"](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume21/19-777/19-777.pdf) (2020). Implementation wise there is e.g. the [`bigtime`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigtime/index.html) package in R.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about VAR, but model selection is well-developed in the context of OLS and should be analogously applicable to VAR.

[LASSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)) is the most commonly used method of model selection. The premise is to penalize choice of a non-zero coefficient for a variable. The variable only receives a nonzero coefficient if doing so reduces the sum of squared residuals in a meaningful manner.

The LASSO method also biases coefficients toward 0. To overcome this, there is a common two-step method of (1) estimating with LASSO to observe which variables have nonzero coefficients and (2) estimating the regular (non-LASSO) model while only restricting to coefficients chosen in the first step.

[Belloni and Chernozhukov](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-19/issue-2/Least-squares-after-model-selection-in-high-dimensional-sparse-models/10.3150/11-BEJ410.full) (2013) is a citation for this two-step approach.